# AS2: Duplicate movieclip to new layer

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

Ok, I know layers dont exist once compiled and that duplicated movieclips cannot be duplicated to new levels but I need some kind of work around here.

I cannot use the library as the movieclip I am duplicating is dynamically generated by actionscript (a graph based on user input over time) and thus cannot be made by me beforehand as it varies.

I need to somehow make a duplicate of this on a layer above the where the original was made, anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of irrelevant now, I had an array of coords from my original production of the movieclip and just decided to use that to create another `with()` the higher leveled mc.